# How to schedule sql script and export data to particular location in IBM Netezza

Tags: sql, ssis, netezza, aginity

I want to schedule sql query script which export results into CSV on weekly basis.  It will help end user to get data weekly. 
Like SQL Server Integration services, I am looking for such service in Netezza.
I will be thankful in case any one aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

The nzsql command is a SQL command interpreter. You can use it on the IBM® Netezza® host or on UNIX client systems to create database objects, run queries, and manage the database.

If you are on a unix based client, you can prepare a shell script with below command and call the script in a weekly cron job (Unix scheduler)

`nzsql -A -t -host IP/HOSTNAME -d DATABASENAME -u USERNAME -pw PASSWORD -f SQL_FILENAME -o OUTPUT_FILENAME.csv`

SQL_FILENAME: Should have the SQL to be used for extraction

> Please note nzsql is not yet available on Windows client systems

Reference:
[IBM Netezza nzsql documentation Link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_nzsql_command.html)